# Limiting a energy term

Tags: limits, physics

A famous Einstein's mass energy equivalence equation is $E= \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$

I need to prove from the above equation is that E = pc. I know that, i will have to limit $m \rightarrow 0$ but failed to do this. Any help?

Comment: Ultimately you want to write $E^2 = m^2c^4 + p^2c^2$. Taking a limit as mass goes to zero doesn't make sense because SR is *not* continuous in this manner. As soon as you introduce mass, the nature of the SR equations changes entirely. This is the source of confusion about "seeing things" in the frame of a photon and such. [This Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy%E2%80%93momentum_relation) is helpful.

Comment: I heard Louis de Broglie proving $E=pc$ using Einstein's famous equation like this $E=mc^2=mc\cdot c=pc$.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

$$\vec{p}=\frac{m \vec{v}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$